# Writing buid id in Fortify

Tags: fortify

I am new to fortify products, I just wonder how to create the build-id in Fortify SCA component.

Currently, I had installed Fortify product in my Ubuntu machine.

thanks ahead

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of the sequence of commands you use to translate and analyze code:

```
sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> -clean
sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> ...
sourceanalyzer -b <build_id> -scan -f myresults.fpr
```

Find more information in the [documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2120/SCA_Help_21.2.0/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think fgk summed it up nicely, but there are two things I wanted to elaborate on ... cuz I got stuck on it.

1. build_id is not related to application==project==folder, go ahead and make it anything you want i.e. ASDF
2. For the translate==build step, If you just want to analyze the current directory you need to add that path aka `.`

Example,

```
#Clean step,
sourceanalyzer -b 'ASDF' -clean
#Translate/Build Step, the `.` path is important,
sourceanalyzer -b 'ASDF' .
#Scan step,
sourceanalyzer -b 'ASDF' -scan -f myresults.fpr
```